# Incorrect results when applying operations to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make an image of a circle by transforming a `numpy matrix` to an image, but I am getting weird missing lines on the image when the input is `50` or more. How can I fix this?

The input determines the size of the matrix, an input of `50` makes a `50 by 50` matrix. I'm a beginner programmer, and this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so please don't be to harsh :) This is my code.

````
from PIL import Image
import itertools
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
inp = int(input("Input size of matrix"))
dt = np.dtype(np.int8)
M = np.zeros((inp, inp), dtype=dt)
A = (list(itertools.product(range(0, inp), repeat=2)))
count1 = 0
for n in A:
    x = (int(n[0]) / (inp - 1)) * 2
    y = (int(n[1]) / (inp - 1)) * 2
    if (x ** 2) + (y ** 2) - (2 * x) - (2 * y) <= -1:
        M[int(x * (inp - 1)/2), int(y * (inp - 1)/2)] = 1
        count1 += 1
print(M)
im = Image.fromarray(M * 255)
im.show()
print("Approximation of pi: " + str(4 * (count1 / inp ** 2))) ```
````

Comment: I said that the weird lines only appeared on values equal to or more than 50 but I realized that the problem occurs on input = 48, but not on input= 49 so I'm not sure what is happening

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line: `M[int(x * (inp - 1)/2), int(y * (inp - 1)/2)] = 1`
Actually, this line assigns 1 twice in some indices and misses some indices because you are using `int()`. Use `round()` to get nearest integer. That will help. Change this line: `M[int(x * (inp - 1)/2), int(y * (inp - 1)/2)] = 1` to this line: `M[round(x * (inp - 1)/2), round(y * (inp - 1)/2)] = 1`

Your code should look like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import itertools
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
inp = int(input("Input size of matrix"))
dt = np.dtype(np.int8)
M = np.zeros((inp, inp), dtype=dt)
A = (list(itertools.product(range(0, inp), repeat=2)))
count1 = 0
for n in A:
    x = (int(n[0]) / (inp - 1)) * 2
    y = (int(n[1]) / (inp - 1)) * 2
    if (x ** 2) + (y ** 2) - (2 * x) - (2 * y) <= -1:
        M[round(x * (inp - 1)/2), round(y * (inp - 1)/2)] = 1
        count1 += 1
print(M)
im = Image.fromarray(M * 255)
im.show()
print("Approximation of pi: " + str(4 * (count1 / inp ** 2)))
```

I think this is another solution that has the expected output also and it is an easy solution without any conversion of float to integer (for indices):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
inp = int(input("Input size of matrix"))
dt = np.dtype(np.int8)
M = np.zeros((inp, inp), dtype=dt)
A = (list(itertools.product(range(0, inp), repeat=2)))
# assign the center
cx,cy=int(inp/2), int(inp/2)
# assign the radius
rad=int(inp/2)
count1 = 0
for n in A:
    # calculate distance of a point from the center
    dist = np.sqrt((n[0]-cx)**2+(n[1]-cy)**2)
    # Assign 1 where dist < rad.
    if dist < rad:
        M[n[0], n[1]] = 1
        count1 += 1

print(M)
im = Image.fromarray(M * 255)
im.show()
print("Approximation of pi: " + str(4 * (count1 / inp ** 2)))
```

Comment: @CarlosViramontes hi, I updated the answer. It has now two solutions. I think the updated answer solved your problem. If you think so, then please accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot, thank you for examining why my code didn't work. it helped me solve another issue i was trying to solve in a different code.